# What is a frame in beamer?

Tags: beamer, presentations

Could you please explain what exactly is a frame in beamer? And how is that a frame is different from a slide? I am trying to shift from MS PowerPoint to `beamer` and would like to clearly understand these concepts.

Comment: In short: A frame is a collection of slides that share a common code (that could contain commands like `\alt` or `\only` etc that will give the difference between the slides inside this frame).

Comment: If you use GIMP, it's the same thing: a frame is an image composed of a slide stack, i.e. transparencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer and adding an example:

A frame is a collection of slides that share a common code (that could contain commands like `\alt` or `\only` etc that will give the difference between the slides inside this frame).

Compile this example to understand more. It contains two frames with a title each... but the first frame is composed by several slides and the second by two slides.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t,label=frameA]{This is the first frame}
    This frame contains code that:

    \begin{itemize}
        \item Will be visible in all the slides of the frame like this line and everything above this \pause
        \item Will be visible after some slide number inside the frame
        and the upcoming slides of it like this particular text that appears after the second slide until the end of the frame.\pause
        \item \alt<3>{Will be different from a slide to the next slide but will occupy the same place -Check this text in the next line-}{Text changed}\pause
        \item We can refer and link to slide 2 of the next frame (labeled `frameB') by writing\\ \texttt{\textbackslash hypertarget$<$2$>$\{frameA\}\{\textbackslash beamerbutton\{I'm on the second slide\}\}}\\in that frame and calling it from here by the command:\\
        \texttt{\textbackslash hyperlink\{labelB2\}\{Press here\}}
    \end{itemize}
    \hyperlink{labelB2}{Press here (to skip slide 1 of frameB)}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=frameB]{Second frame}
    \alt<1>{First Slide}{}
    \alt<2>{Second Slide\par
    \hypertarget<2>{labelB2}{\beamerbutton{I’m on thesecond slide}}}{}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**

A frame can contain just a single slide like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=frameA]{This is the first frame}
    This frame contains code that:

    \begin{itemize}
        \item Will be visible in all the slides of the frame like this line and everything above this
        \item Will be visible in all tlides inside the frame.
        \item Will the same from a slide to the next slide.
        \item We can refer and link to slide 2 of the next frame (labeled `frameB') by writing\\ \{frameA\}\{\textbackslash beamerbutton\{I'm on the second slide\}\}}\\in that frame and calling it from here by the command:\\
        \texttt{\textbackslash hyperlink\{labelB2\}\{Press here\}}
    \end{itemize}
    \hyperlink{labelB}{Press here (to skip slide 1 of frameB)}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=frameB]{Second frame}
    First and only Slide\par
    \hypertarget{labelB}{\beamerbutton{I’m on thesecond slide}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @koleygr this clarifies the picture a bit. I still though I do not understand if it is possible to define one single "slide" as such in `beamer`

Comment: Better is to use `\begin{frame}\frametitle{<title>} ... \end{frame}`than `\begin{frame}{<title>} ... \end{frame}`.

Comment: @Zarko thanks... I used this way because I thought it was better 
(even as more resent) ... But thanks ... I will look about it and take care next time

Comment: @koleygr, in recent `beamer` versions is (somewhere) noted that your approach is deprecated (now is to hot here that I will search through documentation to find this).

Comment: Thanks @Zarko ... may be I thought like this because I used to code like your suggestion but then , found out (much later) this way and I thought I had to adapt this (new for me) method.