# Why is using frametitle the recommended way when using the beamer class?

Tags: beamer, frame-title, frame

I have just read that using `frametitle` explicitly is the recommended way for a frame's title when using the `beamer` package [1], i.e. `\begin{frame}\frametitle{<title>} ... \end{frame}` is recommended over `\begin{frame}{<title>} ... \end{frame}`. Can somebody educate me why that is the case?

A MWE might look as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Some descriptive title}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item bla
        \item bla
        \item bla
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[1] [What is a frame in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504002/what-is-a-frame-in-beamer#comment1273591_504007)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I usually recommend `\frametitle` because it is more powerful, for example, you can use

```
\frametitle<1>{title for first overlay}
\frametitle<2>{another title}
\frametitle<article:0>{A frametitle only for presentation}
```

to change the frametitle between overlays or modes. On can also use

```
\frametitle[short version]{long version}
```

to set a short and long version of the frametitle (which is more an academic example, as there are not a lot themes which will actually make use of the short frametitle...)

I'm also confident that `\frametitle` will continue to work in the future. On the other hand, the code which, behind the scenes, powers `\begin{frame}{...}` is more or less a series of dirty hacks. In case this code breaks for whatever reason in the future, I'm not sure if there will be considerable efforts to keep this syntax alive. Removing this syntax would have a lot of advantages. The beamer code would get much simpler and easier to maintain and one could avoid a lot of problems caused by this syntax. Everybody who ever tried to use a group at the start of frame can probably relate...

And just a personal preference: the syntax `\begin{frame}{...}` as such is just weird. The frame title is optional, nevertheless it looks like a mandatory argument -- confusing ...

Comment: Hadn't thought of the example with changing frametitles, besides, I agree `\begin{frame}{...}` is somewhat weird compared to using `\frametitle`. Thanks for the elaborated answer!

Comment: @Alf You're welcome!

Comment: The `beamer` user guide still contains examples using `\begin{frame}{...}`, and even more: the official syntax for the `frame` environment is `\begin{frame}<⟨overlay specification⟩>[<⟨default overlay specification⟩>][⟨options⟩]{⟨title⟩}{⟨subtitle⟩}`. (In French, we say “Shoemakers are the worst shod” ;)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé It is valid syntax, just not what I would recommend for the reasons detailed above

Comment: Agreeing with *all*  said (+1) but playing as devil's advocate (1) It is not the only thing   weird in Beamer, so one more doesn't matter too much. (2) `\begin{frame}{Atitle}{A subtitle}` is munch handy and readable that `\begin{frame}\frametitle{A title}\framesubtitle{A subtitle}` and (3) remove this syntax would be a pain for people that already have a lot of old presentations  that need regular updates (i.e., teachers) and some day all presentations stop working unexpectedly, even if there are a `\typeout` advising that there is an easy fix.

Comment: @Fran The backwards compatibility is the reason that the code is still in beamer. As long as it keeps working, there are currently no plans to actively remove it.